# Request location updates based only on min-distance

Tags: android, location, locationmanager, userlocation, showuserlocation

I am developing a location based application in which i want to get location after movement of meter from previous position. I don't want to give minimum time in

```
void requestLocationUpdates (String provider, 
            long minTime, 
            float minDistance, 
            LocationListener listener)
```

Is there any way to request location updates based only upon minimum distance?

Comment: Is there any way to check whether phone's location is on or off?

Comment: Read [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html), if you pass minTime 0, then it considers only minDistance parameter.

Comment: Here is the answer for your question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44882705/getting-location-updates-based-on-time-interval-or-displacement answered by @blackkara

Answer (score 1):

Here is all the information I could find ([requestLocationUpdates](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html)) :

> The minDistance parameter can also be used to control the frequency of
>   location updates. If it is greater than 0 then the location provider
>   will only send your application an update when the location has
>   changed by at least minDistance meters, **AND** at least minTime
>   milliseconds have passed. However it is more difficult for location
>   providers to save power using the minDistance parameter, so minTime
>   should be the primary tool to conserving battery life.